# Trouble clearing overlay when i reload a new set of markers in gmaps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a gmap and I only want to display markers in the viewable area.  I have added a listener to get the bounds of the map and call gather the markers within the bounds.  the problem is that when i bounds change, i want to clear the map and reload with the updated markers.  currently the map will just continue to reload the markers on top of each other which makes the map extremely slow.  I have tried:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
    clearOverlays();
    loadMapFromCurrentBounds(map);
});
```

And that will not load any markers at all.  I have also tried:

```
function loadMapFromCurrentBounds(map) {
    clearOverlays();
```

And this will not load any markers either.  Below is the code that will load all markers and functions as i want it to with the exception of clearing the old markers when the bounds change.

```
function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
    loadMapFromCurrentBounds(map);
}); 
}

function clearOverlays() {
  if (markers) {
    for (i in markers) {
      markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}

function loadMapFromCurrentBounds(map) {
    clearOverlays();

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

var bounds = map.getBounds(); // First, determine the map bounds

var swPoint = bounds.getSouthWest();  // Then the points
var nePoint = bounds.getNorthEast();

     // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
var searchUrl = 'Viewport_Search.php?west=' + swPoint.lat() + '&east=' + nePoint.lat() + '&south=' + swPoint.lng() + '&north=' + nePoint.lng();
  downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });

}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

Please help... I have been beating my head against the computer all night researching and trying to figure this out.  Feel free to email and/or ask for any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You cant remove all markers, but it is possible to setMap to null on every visible marker.
I am doing it like that

1. add markers array to map object
2. add clearAllMarkers function to map object
3. every marker is added to the map is also added to markers array
4. clearAllMarkers function is something like that:

> ```
>    for (var idx=0;idx<=map.markers.length;idx++){
>                map.markers[idx].setMap(null);
>    }
> ```

I belive you are adding separate markers object to you're markers array. You're markers array should be full of markers references!!!

```
var map = []; //elrado's code

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

  map.markers = [];//elrado's code (add narkers.array to map object)

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
    loadMapFromCurrentBounds(map);
}); 
}

function clearOverlays() {
  if (map.markers) {
    for (i in map.markers) { //Might be you'll need to use map.markers.length
      markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    map.markers = [];//reinit map.markers.array
  }
}

function loadMapFromCurrentBounds(map) {
    clearOverlays();

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

var bounds = map.getBounds(); // First, determine the map bounds

var swPoint = bounds.getSouthWest();  // Then the points
var nePoint = bounds.getNorthEast();

     // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
var searchUrl = 'Viewport_Search.php?west=' + swPoint.lat() + '&east=' + nePoint.lat() + '&south=' + swPoint.lng() + '&north=' + nePoint.lng();
  downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
      });
      map.markers.push(marker);//elrado's code
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });

}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

I have to warn you that this was written from the head (no test), but something like that should work. Basicly you are setting setMap(null) on separate markers not on objects you're showing on the map.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned and it still continues to preform the same way.  I added a button to clear the markers manually, but interestingly it does not remove the markers...?.?.?  Why would the markers not clear when i call the function manually?  your help is very much appreciated

Comment: Try adding click event to marker and call this.setMap(null) on it. And also check number of markers on the map. It is possible that you have double number of markers there (more markers on the same lat, lng).

Comment: i added the event marker, and it removed the marker that the event was triggered to. but it still will not remove all markers.  below is the link to my project....can you take a peak.  I am sure it is something obvious that i am missing.  http://www.aptrentalnetwork.com

Comment: @nicksonline clear overlays works in Opera and in Firefox. When I opened youre page I say multiple markers that were cleared when i clicked clear overlay and shown when I clicked show All overlays.

Comment: elrado, thanks for your help.  I was able to fix it yesterday. I was not setting up my array of markers correctly before.

Comment: If I helped you please mark ansawer as correct if no please edit you're question code so that others may benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the complete code solution to the problem..  Thanks for your help.

```
var map;    //elrado's code 
var markersArray = [];   //elrados's code   create array for markers       

function load() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.553029,-112.054017),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
    clearOverlays()
    loadMapFromCurrentBounds(map);
}); 
}


function clearOverlays() {  //clear overlays function
  if (markersArray) {
for (i in markersArray) {
  markersArray[i].setMap(null);
 }
}
}


function loadMapFromCurrentBounds(map) {    
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

var bounds = map.getBounds(); // First, determine the map bounds

var swPoint = bounds.getSouthWest();  // Then the points
var nePoint = bounds.getNorthEast();

     // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
var searchUrl = 'Viewport_Search.php?west=' + swPoint.lat() + '&east=' + nePoint.lat() + '&south=' + swPoint.lng() + '&north=' + nePoint.lng();
  downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
      });
      markersArray.push(marker);          //eldorado's code Define the array to put markers in

      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }

  });

}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```